# Possible typo in N.L. Carothers' Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I have been working through the chapter on *Continuous Maps Between Metric Spaces* and came across the following that I believe to have a typo in it:

> Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies  $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is continuous at some point $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that there is some constant $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(ax) = ax$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Shouldn't the question be asking us to prove $f(x) = ax$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Which I actually showed to be true in my undergraduate years going by the following rough outline:

First showng that $f(0) = 0$ and that $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Then, that for any finite sum of real numbers $a_{1}+...+a_{n}$ we have that $f(a_{1}+...+a_{n}) = f(a_{1})+...+f(a_{n})$. Lastly, by using the last few steps we can show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(nx) = nf(x)$ and $f(\frac{1}{n}x) = \frac{1}{n}f(x)$. Which from here we can conclude that $f(x) = ax$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, with this question I don't see how we could possibly show that $f(ax) = ax$ given only that $f$ is continuous and additive.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a typo. $f(ax) = ax$ would imply that $f(x) = x$ is the only solution.

Comment: @MartinR thank goodness - I have been working on this problem forever and knew there was no way it was stated correctly.